# Is there a way to auto detect a camera (USB) on windows with Java/JavaFX?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

My goal is to have a java application running, when the camera is plugged in or already plugged in, the program can auto detect the camera. After writing that sentence it doesn't seem possible in distinguishing between the USB drives on windows.

Can someone help me with pointing me in the right direction with allowing the user to specify the camera location? If the camera location is specified i should be able to auto-generate some sort of list of jpeg files on it correct?

My overall goal is to have a user enter a "job number", then from the camera (auto-detected or user location specified), the program automatically takes all the photos that exist on it, dump them into a folder named after the job number, then erase the photos on the camera.

It's like an auto photo storage dump pretty much.

I'm currently working with Eclipse and the JavaFX plug-in with using SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

libjitsi is an advanced Java media library for secure real-time audio/video communication. **It allows applications to capture, playback, stream, encode/decode and encrypt audio and video flows.** It also allows for advanced features such as audio mixing, handling multiple streams, participation in audio and video conferences.

Originally libjitsi was part of the Jitsi client source code but we decided to spin it off so that other projects can also use it.

libjitsi is distributed under the terms of the LGPL.

**Feature list**

Video capture and rendering on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Video codecs: H.264 and H.263 (VP8 coming in early 2013)

.
.
.

[More Info](https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi)